# Google Reader Archive feed not valid xml?

Tags: python, rss

I want to get the most recent 10,000 entries from CNN's top stories RSS feed. I'm using the following python program to do this, connecting to Google's archive tool as follows:

```
import string
import urllib2
from xml.dom import minidom

feedAddr = "http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss?r=n&n=1000"

feedString = urllib2.build_opener().open(urllib2.Request(feedAddr)).read()
xml = minidom.parseString(feedString)
items = xml.getElementsByTagName("item")

for item in items:
   titleNode = item.childNodes[1]
   linkNode = item.childNodes[3]

   titleString = titleNode.firstChild.data
   linkString = linkNode.firstChild.data

   print titleString, linkString
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 1285, column 4
```

Is this a problem with Google's archiving tool or feed generator? Is it a problem with my Python code? I'm getting the feed url from this page, splicing in the CNN feed url as seen above:

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/06/reconstruct-feeds-history-using-google.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you actually examined the data returned by urllib?  Are you sure you're getting a feed and not something else?  Google Reader requires authentication and if you attempt to load that URL without authentication you will get back an HTML error page.  Try this:

```
feedString = urllib2.build_opener().open(urllib2.Request(feedAddr)).read()
open('feed.xml', 'w').write(feedString)
```

And examine the `feed.xml` file.

Also, you can grab it from CNN directly by just stripping off the `http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/' part and using:

```
http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss?r=n&n=1000.
```

This returns a valid `RSS` feed.

Comment: Yep, suggestion of using CNN RSS directly is really worth.

Comment: Hitting it directly won't work. It just returns a partial list of the ten or so most recent stories. You're right about it needing authentication, but directing my browser to http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss?r=n&n=1000 gives what I want. So I'll just open it from a file.

Also, you should really close your files. Python won't actually write the file until it gets closed.

Comment: That was a ridiculous comment to make to someone who is helping you out with a snippet of code.  Of *course* it's not a complete program.  Geez...

Comment: Didn't mean to offend. I just often make that mistake of not closing the file and I wonder why it's not being created. Not all of us code in Python enough to know basic facts. I'm learning :)